# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, nullpointerexception, filtering

When I am using a PrimeFaces 5.2 `<p:dataTable>` with filtering,

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable"  var="cus"
             value="#{customerListBean.customerList}" 
             paginator="true" rows="3" 
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="3,9,12,15" rowStatePreserved="true">
    <p:column sortBy="#{cus.firstname}" filterBy="#{cus.firstname}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="First Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cus.firstname}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="#{cus.lastname}" filterBy="#{cus.lastname}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cus.lastname}" />
    </p:column>              
    <p:column sortBy="#{cus.cellPhone}" filterBy="#{cus.cellPhone}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Phone Number" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cus.cellPhone}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

and this managed bean,

```
@ManagedBean
public class CustomerListBean {

    private List<Customer> customerList;

    private CustomerListDAO cc=new CustomerListDAO();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        customerList=cc.getAllCustomer();
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

}
```

then the following error occurs:

```
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/welcomePrimefaces.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter(FilterFeature.java:141)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?